# C# Razor Resource - NT Authentication

Tags: c#, razor

New to `C#` and `Razor` but looks very similar to what I'm used to which is `Classic ASP`. However I was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction for a good resource?

The `asp.net` site is a little all over the place

Anyway, specifically, how to I check for and then display the username of a user logged in via **NT authentication**? Is it possible to set **NT authentication** for a subset of pages or does it have to be for the whole site?

Thanks

Comment: what are some things your wanting to use it for?

Answer (score 0):

There is an article in asp.net website, [Introduction to ASP.NET Web Programming Using the Razor Syntax](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/basics/2-introduction-to-asp-net-web-programming-using-the-razor-syntax) that looks like might be helpful to you.

You don't specify if your application uses razor inside a MVC View. If this is the case, authentication code certainly shouldn't be there.

If you're using webpages, then have a look at this [tutorial](http://mikepope.com/blog/DisplayBlog.aspx?permalink=2298) for windows authentication.

Comment: That's the site I was referring to as not being brilliant :-(

No MVC here